# Summarize Custom field in Account History Report

Tags: reporting, account, accounthistory

Is there a way to summarize a custom field value (Old Value, New Value) in a Account History Report. I tried everything but it just doesn't provide me that option.
See image below. I've marked everything with colors showing what exactly I want to summarize. I want to use this so i can track monthly revenue for a client inside the Account object.

Thanks,
Darko

[image]

Comment: what is the use case here? summarizing values in a change log seems odd to me.

Comment: Hi crop1645, 
What i want to achieve is that i will track the revenue share for that specific account for 12 months. I want to do this without creating fields per month and update them(12 fields for 1 year. That means for more years double the fields). So what i was seeking is something like this. If you have other suggestion please share it will be helpful to me. Thanks,

Comment: @James has the right approach. It sounds like you are mining existing data to try and reconstruct revenue history. I'd build the custom object, change your business logic to keep the custom object in sync with changes in the base record and then do a data migration from historical AccountHistory records into the custom object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the `AccountHistory` Object level, the OldValue/NewValue fields are of type String, so you will not be able to perform any type of aggregation; despite only displaying what appears to be a single data type (number).

To acheive what you seek, you'll need to build a custom field on Account and name it **Prior Value**.  From here, you can create a simple Workflow rule which will update the **Prior Value** field with the old value on change.

If you are wanting to track Revenue for the Account, for **n** number of months (really any time period), then I would recommend creating a Custom Object named **Revenue Transaction**.   So, instead of having users change a value for a specific field on the Account, they would simply enter a new **Revenue Transaction** under the Account.    This way, you will know exactly *Who* and *When* an entry was made (great for auditing), and you can more effectively manage the data.

You'll need, at a minimum, these 3 fields:

1. Account
2. Amount
3. Transaction Date

As a bonus you can make the relationship Master-Detail when creating the Custom Object, which will allow you to summarize the Total Revenue at the Account level, and the entire **Revenue Transaction** table is ***fully reportable*** out of the box.

Comment: Hi James,
Can you please elaborate more on this. It will help me allot. What will this Prior Value show me exactly? If its changed how can i summarize the Total value for 12 months for that specific account?

Thanks,

Comment: @DarkoTodorovski If I understand you correctly, you are wanting to track EVERY change, not just the current and prior value, correct?  as crop1645 mentioned, summarizing a change log is a bit odd; however, you are on the right design track with not wanting to create a separate field for each month.     I'll update my answer with a couple more approaches.

Comment: Hey James, yes i want to be able to sumarize every month because basically i will change the field once a month. So this way i want to track all the summary for the future months that come. I tried your step but i am a bit stuck. Why do I need transaction date when i have the edit field date in the history? Also why i need the Account when i can group them by account in a matrix report? The problem that I am experiencing is that i cannot summarize the old/new value because it's string :(

Comment: I followed your steps and they worked perfectly. Thanks allot for your assistance it was really helpful.

Comment: Glad it helped!  Sometimes you have to try a different approach (which may not work for every scenario).